# What is the difference in "Processing by Contoller#method as */*" and "Processing by BillsController#show as HTML"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, methods

All of my rails 3.2.2 ActiveRecord methods are being executed twice. I noticed that each execution is being processed differently, see the examples I grabbed from the console below...

```
Started GET "/api/bills/Jeremy%20Fox" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-20 23:16:43 -0400
Processing by BillsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"username"=>"Jeremy Fox"}
  BillsForUsers Load (2.4ms)  SELECT "bills_for_users".* FROM "bills_for_users" WHERE "bills_for_users"."billusername" = 'Jeremy Fox'
Completed 200 OK in 47ms (Views: 11.2ms | ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)


Started GET "/api/bills/Jeremy%20Fox" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-20 23:16:44 -0400
Processing by BillsController#show as */*
  Parameters: {"username"=>"Jeremy Fox"}
  BillsForUsers Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "bills_for_users".* FROM "bills_for_users" WHERE "bills_for_users"."billusername" = 'Jeremy Fox'
Completed 200 OK in 33ms (Views: 28.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
```

Can anyone explain to me why all of my ActiveRecord methods are being executed twice and/or what the difference is between `Processing by BillsController#show as HTML` and `Processing by BillsController#show as */*`?

Thanks.

Comment: No one? No one can explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the problem was actually the JSONView Chrome extension. As it states in the options menu...

> Use safe method to parse HTTP response (*)
>
> (*) : safe method forces the browser to send an extra HTTP request to get the raw HTTP content.

After spending days trying to figure out what I was doing wrong in my code, it was actually just chrome!

Hope no one else runs into this stupid issue.

-Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

I've been grappling with this same issue.  The HTML Validator Chrome extension is also guilty (with none of the fine print.)

In my case, I'm calling a ModestModel-backed search request, so the first hit (and rendering) was succeeding, followed by a phantom 500 as my non-DB search model was out of scope and nil on the second request.

Thanks, Jeremy!